# OpenCart увеличивает вес изображний при resize, как быть?

Tags: php, изображения, opencart, resize

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой в OpenCart 2. Есть изображение, допустим, 1000x1000 в jpg. Перед загрузкой в магазин, я оптимизирую данное изображение, сокращая примерно 70% от его изначального веса. В магазине данное изображение кропится до 900x900 (предположим), но, парадокс, становится весить чуть больше, чем оптимизированное 1000 на 1000 до загрузки. С учетом того, что в библиотеке image (по умолчанию в OpenCart) стоит качество изображений 90.

Собственно вопрос, что можно предпринят, чтобы изображения не увеличивались в весе после кропа? Ибо из-за этого, страница порой весит на 100-150 кб больше, чем могла бы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://opencartforum.com/topic/28098-vopros-optimizacii-izobrazheniy-gd/

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, хотя до сих пор не понимаю, как заранее уже оптимизированное мной изображение может быть раздуто ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер скачет за счёт использования различных методов сжатия изображений, используемых вашей штатной сжималкой и opencart. Который, в 99% случаев юзает Imagick (Image Magick) т.к. это стандартный обработчик изображений на разного рода недорогих vps-ах. 
Поиграться с качеством (и соответствено с размером) изображений можете в файле `catalog/model/tool/image.php`. там найти строчку `$image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);` и добавить в метод save второй целочисленный аргумент, который будет равен quality картинки (от 0 до 100). По умолчанию, кажется там стоит 90, но в вашем шаблоне может и больше.